# Threaded DNS server in Java

Tags: java, dns

I'm trying to create a simple DNS server in java. Here is my code:

```
public class DNSServer{
        public static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 6052;
        private static ServerSocket sock = null;
        static Socket client;

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            try
            {
                ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(DEFAULT_PORT);

                /* now listen for connections */
                while(true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Server is listening...\n");
                    client = sock.accept();
                    System.out.println("Client connected\n");

                    // create a separate thread
                    // to service the request
                    Thread worker = new Thread(new Connection(client));
                    worker.start(); 

                }
            }   
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println(ioe);
            }
              finally {
                    //close Socket
                    try {
                        client.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        System.err.println(ioe);
                    }
            }

        }
```

}

```
public class Connection implements Runnable {

private Socket client=null;
private BufferedReader fromClient = null;
private PrintWriter toClient = null;
private String hostAddress;

public Connection(Socket client) 
{
    this.client=client;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
    fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    toClient = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

    String nameRequest = fromClient.readLine(); //Reading from Socket
    InetAddress hostInetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(nameRequest);
    hostAddress = hostInetAddress.getHostAddress();
    toClient.println(hostAddress); //Writing the Result IP address (as a String) to the Socket

    }
    catch(UnknownHostException uhe){
        hostAddress = "Unknown Host";
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        System.err.println(ioe);
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            fromClient.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe);
        }
        toClient.close();
        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe);
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
public class DNSClient {
    public static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 6052;
    private static Socket sock;
    private static BufferedReader fromServer;
    private static PrintWriter toServer;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        if(args.length==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Usage: java DNSClient [host name]");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
            sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", DEFAULT_PORT );

            toServer = new PrintWriter(args[0]); //send hostname to server
            fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream())); //read host IP from server

            //print output
            System.out.println(args[0] + " = " + fromServer.readLine());
            }

            catch(IOException ioe){
                System.err.println(ioe);
            }
            finally{
                toServer.close();
                try {
                    fromServer.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.err.println(ioe);
                }
                try {
                    sock.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.err.println(ioe);
                }
            }



        }
    }
```

}

But when I supply an argument url and press enter , the program gets stuck..
What could be the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Edit: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H741V.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through  your code with a debugger?

Comment: Nope, our lecturer said that debugging is useless here since we run everything via command prompt.

Comment: You don't _have_ to run everything via the command prompt.  Seriously, step through it with a debugger - you'll find the process _extremely_ useful.

Comment: If you're not willing to use an IDE and debugger, at least add more logging and add the output to your post.

Comment: You should demonstrate that you understand the topic you have asked, not just copy/paste someones code to SO.

Comment: What do you mean someone's code? I wrote that code ..